# How to box aligned equations

Tags: amsmath, boxes, framed

```
\boxed{
\begin{align*}
x &= 1 \\
y &= 1
\end{align*}
}
```

obviously doesn't work/compile..

```
\begin{framed}
\begin{align*}
x &= 1 \\
y &= 1
\end{align*}
\end{framed}
```

sort of work, but it will look ugly because the box is unnecessarily big.

Comment: This is your first question, hence, Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

Use the sledge hammer trio : `amsmath`, `empheq` and `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[theorems,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,
enhanced jigsaw,arc=0pt,boxrule=0.5pt,boxsep=0pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,colback=white,colframe=black,
#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align*}
    x &= 1 \\
    y &= 1
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust `left`, `right` etc as suitable, they are margins for the box.

Comment: Thanks Harish, I've meant to ask this actually: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240310/box-aligned-equation-under-deep-itemization

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand\exactfbox[1]{\fbox{\hskip1em#1\hskip1em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\exactfbox]{align*}
 x &= 1 \\
 y &= 1
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]