# Box aligned equation under (deep) itemization

Tags: pdftex, framed

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}

\begin{itemize}
\item[1.] zz
\begin{itemize}
\item[1.1]

\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align}
x \;&=\; x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = x_6 = 0 \\
y \;&=\; y_1 = y_2 = y_3 = y_4 = y_5 = y_6 = 0 
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\item[1.2]
\end{itemize}
\item[2.]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The box will be mis-sized, not boxing the entire equations body.

Comment: Could you specify what goes in the "widefbox" definition?

Comment: I just copied from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109900/how-can-i-box-multiple-aligned-equations

Comment: Please do not post only fragments of code.

Comment: Equation seems to be well-boxed. Please specify your actual problem.

Comment: If you compile it, you will see the box is off. Does this site compile a doc?

Comment: Your code didn't compile which made it slightly useless. I have added the missing commands, but to me the placement of the box looks fine so you need to explain what you mean by the box being off. Btw, your use of `\;` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

The equations are centred with respect to the left margin of the current itemize environment and the right margin of the page, not taking into account the equation number. A work around could be adding `\hphantom{tag}` to the right of the `empheq` environment. I also managed to get the item number vertically aligned with the first line of the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[1.] zz
        \begin{itemize}%[leftmargin = *]
          \item[1.1]
                \leavevmode\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\abovedisplayshortskip}
                \begin{subequations}
                  \begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox, right = \hphantom{2a}]{align}
                    x \;&=\; x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = x_6 = 0 \\
                    y \;&=\; y_1 = y_2 = y_3 = y_4 = y_5 = y_6 = 0
                  \end{empheq}
                \end{subequations}
                \noindent Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
          \item[1.2]
        \end{itemize}
  \item[2.]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: doesn't compile -- you're missing a closing brace at the end of  the definition of `\widefbox`.  also, `amssymb` is needed either; you probably meant `amsmath`, but with `empheq` that's taken care of.

Comment: Oh yes! Bad copy-paste… Corrected now. Thanks for pointing it :o)

Comment: Thanks a lot! just curious, do you generate the image using the site? or do you have to take screen-shot and upload?

Comment: I take a screenshot of my pdf viewer, after I've zoomed.